# Android конвертировать PDF в ImageView?

Tags: android

Как отобразить PDF в ImageView?
Чтобы получить pdf надо его скачать из сети.

Может есть готовое решение уже?

Comment: Обязательно в ImageView отображать надо? Если да, то посмотрите тут как из pdf получить Bitmap https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814758/need-help-to-convert-a-pdf-page-into-bitmap-in-android-java.  Если цель - просто отобразить, не важно как и где - то попробуйте вот эту первую попавшуюся либу с GitHub: https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

Comment: спасибо. Подойдет)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, В след раз когда будете советать. Говорите сразу что такие либы весят 16 метров. 

Мне легче самому бибилотеку написать чем это чудо испольщовать))

Comment: Я ничего не советовал. Я просто вбил в гугл `android pdf viewer library` и кинул в коммент 2 первые ссылки.

Comment: Короче я использовать WebVIew и все норм)). Не ну реально 16 метров ради либы это ужас)